# Install to different location (/root) using dpkg

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am a little new to Linux and currently running Mint 17.  I want to have more control over where everything is installed (i.e. `/root` vs `/home`) and see if I can install to `/root` without editing `/etc/apt/sources.list`. (specifically Eclipse Luna and RStudio).

I can just use `dpkg` but what is the appropriate location in `/root`?  guess that's just a long winded way to ask where `apt-get` downloads to, and can I just install to that location without editing any files?

Comment: Your question sounds confused. Mint installs things into standard locations in your system such as `/usr`. I don't understand what you mean by `/root` vs `/home`. Mint does not install binary packages to either of these.

Comment: I have $/home$ as a different partition than $/root$ and its getting cluttered b/c of wine programs.  I want to install (specifically Rstudio) into the root partition w/o cluttering up root from a source not listed in /etc/apt/sources.list.  I guess Im just trying to figure out and appropriate location to extract the tgz file to.

Comment: by root v home i just meant outside of the home folder.

Comment: Mint will not install anything in the home directory. The home directory is getting cluttered because of wine programs? I'm not that familiar with wine. Can you be more specific about what you are doing? And can't you install those wine programs somewhere else?

Comment: nevermind.  I figured what I was doing incorrectly.  thank you though

Answer (score 1):

The `/usr/local` and `/opt` directories are typically used for the installation of local programs system-wide. Typically you can either put the new binaries in `/usr/local/bin` or symlink them there so that they're still in the default user $PATH (so they can just run `program` without specifying the exact path).

Answer (score -2):

I Think you need to change your home folder path in `/etc/passwd` fond your user and change the folder reboot and its done.

I don't recommend you to install as `root` and I not recommend to change the root home folder.

Better Way is ADD new user, added to your `sudoers` file change the home folder for this user.